# How to retrieve and assign current user object to a field in Wagtail admin?

Tags: django-models, wagtail

I have a few Django models that I display in the admin using wagtail’s modelAdmin. few of the fields in the models are referencing the user model. Since I’m not creating the form/page and it’s handled by wagtail, how do I pass the current user object to the field when it’s saved? That is, the created and updated by fields should have the current user object assigned to them.

See code snippet below, currently I'm assigning the user manually by querying, instead I'd like to get the current user.

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

from wagtail.admin.forms import WagtailAdminPageForm

STATUS_CHOICES = (
    (1, 'Active'),
    (2, 'Inactive')
)


class BasePageForm(WagtailAdminPageForm):

    def save(self, commit=True):
        auth_user_model = get_user_model()
        default_user = auth_user_model.objects.get(username='admin')
        page = super().save(commit=False)

        if not page.pk:
            page.created_by = default_user
            page.updated_by = default_user
        else:
            page.updated_by = default_user

        if commit:
            page.save()
        return page


class BaseModel(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='created%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related'
    )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='updated%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related'
    )
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=1)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True  # Set this model as Abstract

    base_form_class = BasePageForm
```

Comment: Please show your models.

Comment: @DanSwain, see the update, thanks!

Comment: I researched this several months ago for a similar need (trying to access the `request` object upon saving a model instance.  Wagtail's `ModelAdmin` is not based upon Django's.  Django's `ModelAdmin` has a `save_model` method that you can override, but I just looked at the code for both `ModelAdmin` definitions again and still can't see any way to do what you're trying to do with the Wagtail's `ModelAdmin`.  I hope someone else can help out here.